# Enum values as class function name

Tags: typescript, webpack, enums, vuex

When using Vuex before, I was able to use enum values as funtion names for both my actions and mutations like so:

```
// ./store/modules/test/actions.ts

import { Actions } from '@/store';
import { ActionTree } from 'vuex';

export default ActionTree<any,any>{
  [Actions.TEST_ACTION](){
    console.log('in action');
  }
}
```

But when trying to do so within a class:

```js
// ./store/modules/test.ts

import { Actions } from '@/store';
import { Action, Module, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';

@Module
export default class Test extends VuexModule {

  @Action
  public async [Actions.TEST_ACTION](): Promise<void> {
    console.log('in action');
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'TEST_ACTION' of undefined
    at eval (test.ts?f2af:4)
// Same line as 'export default class Test extends VuexModule'
```

There are no errors in my editor (vscode), nothing is attempting to call this function (no calls to dispatch), and the `Actions` enum is being exported:

```
export enum Actions {
  TEST_ACTION = 'testAction'
}
```

If I instead do the following, I no longer receive the error:

```
@Action
public async testAction(): Promise<void> {
  console.log('in action');
}
```

Update:
If the enum lives in the same file, there are no errors:

```js
// ./store/modules/test.ts

import { Action, Module, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';

export enum Actions {
  TEST_ACTION = 'testAction'
}

@Module
export default class Test extends VuexModule {

  @Action
  public async [Actions.TEST_ACTION](): Promise<void> {
    console.log('in action');
  }
}
```

While that will work, it's not ideal. Could this be a webpack problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to access the function TEST_ACTION on a class before its initialized

Comment: No actions have been dispatched at the point where the error is occurring. The issue stems from `main.ts` on the line `import store from '@/store'.

Comment: That's wierd it sounds like you  imported actions wrong